# Reason for being off-topic missing from list?

Tags: bug

In the list of reasons for closing a question for being off-topic, there was one along the lines of "This question is not about signal processing as defined in the help center".

I don't see that option any more -- was it removed intentionally?

Answer (score 1):

That was probably me!  I'm not sure what happened. I saw that the "default" off-topic reason was duplicated in the custom reasons. So I deleted the custom reason, and tried to enable another one (about homework, which we seem to be getting a few of).

But when I go to that mod page now, ALL the custom reasons have been deleted.

The odd things is, the reasons you're asking about is still there as the default.

[image]

Comment: Peter, thanks for looking into it. The wording there is very confusing... the "default" reason seems to be shown only when "no two off-topic reasons match", whatever that means?

Comment: @MBaz I think it's just if other (now non-existent) reasons are chosen, that's the one that is used when four (different) selections are made by the reviewers. I think.